# Make columns sortable in admin products list panel in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, product

I added the column with the highest value of the offer. And then I would like to make it sortable. I've prepared this:

// asl this will add extra column in the product list

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', array($this,'show_product_offers_amounts'),15 );
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', array($this,'show_product_offers_amount_max'), 10, 2 );
```

// asl show the column

```
function show_product_offers_amounts($columns){
    $columns['orig_offer_amount'] = 'Amount';
    return $columns;
 }
```

// asl add the datas to column

```
function show_product_offers_amount_max( $column, $postid ) {            
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $column == 'orig_offer_amount' ) {
        $offers_max = $wpdb->get_var( " select max(meta_value)
                        from ".$wpdb->postmeta."
                        where meta_key='orig_offer_amount'
                            and meta_value!=''
                            and post_id in(
                                select p.post_id
                                from ".$wpdb->postmeta." as p
                                where p.meta_key='orig_offer_product_id' and
                                    p.meta_value=".$postid.")" 
                   );

        if($offers_max > 0){
            echo '<mark style="color: #3973aa;font-size: 13px;font-weight: 500;background: 0 0;line-height: 1;">'.$offers_max.'</mark>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<span class="na">–</span>';
        }
    }

}
```

// asl register the column as sortable

```
function price_column_register_sortable( $columns ) {
    $columns['orig_offer_amount'] = 'orig_offer_amount';

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_sortable_columns', 'price_column_register_sortable' );
function price_column_orderby( $vars ) {
    if ( isset( $vars['orderby'] ) && 'price' == $vars['orderby'] ) {

        $offers_max = $wpdb->get_var( " select max(meta_value)
                        from ".$wpdb->postmeta."
                        where meta_key='orig_offer_amount'
                            and meta_value!=''
                            and post_id in(
                                select p.post_id
                                from ".$wpdb->postmeta." as p
                                where p.meta_key='orig_offer_product_id' and
                                    p.meta_value=".$postid.")" 
                   );

        if($offers_max > 0){
            $offers_max = $offers_max;
        }
        else{
            $offers_max = 0;;
        }                   


        $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
            'meta_key' => 'orig_offer_amount',
            'orderby' => $offers_max
        ) );
    }

    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'price_column_orderby' );
```

This code makes that wordpress recognize the column as sortable. But it doesn't sort properly.

Any idea?

Using LoicTheAztec suggestion I prepared something like this:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'new_postmeta_to_products' );
function new_postmeta_to_products($post_id){
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    if($post_type == 'products') {

        global $wpdb;
        $maxId = $wpdb->get_var( " select post_id
                                from ".$wpdb->postmeta."
                                where meta_key='orig_offer_amount'
                                    and meta_value!=''
                                    and post_id in(
                                        select p.post_id
                                        from ".$wpdb->postmeta." as p
                                        where p.meta_key='orig_offer_product_id' and
                                            p.meta_value=".$post_id.")
                                    order by meta_value desc limit 1" 
                           );    

        add_post_meta($post_id,'offer_max_id',$maxId);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work :( maybe because $post_id

Comment: To get this sortable, you should register the product offers amount max as product meta data value… Without that you will not be able to make it sortable. Also this will make your code much more lighter as your code actually is generating a lot of requests to database.

Comment: That's you again. You must be good :)))
You have probably right. I'll think about how to do this.

Comment: I prepare some snippet and I would like to show you. But I can't put it to comment. How do this in a proper way?

Comment: I edited my question and I added it at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to LoicTheAztec's hints I've prepared some snippet. First I've added new postmeta for product, when is created:

```
add_post_meta($post_id, 'offers_max_id', null);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'offers_max_value', null);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'offers_count', null);
```

Then, a few lines to set the new postmeta when an offer is created in www/wp-content/plugins/offers-for-woocommerce/public/class-offers-for-woocommerce.php in function new_offer_form_submit() :

```
global $post;
$_product = get_post_meta($parent_post_id, 'offer_product_id', true);

global $wpdb;
$offerMax = $wpdb->get_results( " select post_id, meta_value
                        from ".$wpdb->postmeta."
                        where meta_key='orig_offer_amount'
                            and meta_value!=''
                            and post_id in(
                                select p.post_id
                                from ".$wpdb->postmeta." as p
                                where p.meta_key='orig_offer_product_id' and
                                    p.meta_value=".$_product.")
                            order by meta_value desc limit 1" 
                   ,ARRAY_N);    
update_post_meta($_product, 'offers_max_id', $offerMax[0][0]);
update_post_meta($_product, 'offers_max_value', $offerMax[0][1]);

 $offerCount = $wpdb->get_var( "select count(post_id) 
                                 from ".$wpdb->postmeta." 
                                 where meta_key='orig_offer_product_id' and
                                     meta_value=".$_product
                             );
 update_post_meta($_product, 'offers_count', $offerCount);
```

Then, we must add new columns for products' admin panel in function.php:

```
// asl show the column
function my_cpt_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns["offermaxid"] = "OfferId";
    $columns["offercount"] = "Offers";
    $columns["offermaxvalue"] = "Amount";
    $columns["dateofend"] = "EndTime";
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-product_columns', 'my_cpt_columns');

// asl take a data to the column
function my_cpt_column( $colname, $cptid ) {
     if ( $colname == 'offermaxid')
          echo get_post_meta( $cptid, 'offers_max_id', true );
     if ( $colname == 'offercount')
          echo get_post_meta( $cptid, 'offers_count', true );       
     if ( $colname == 'offermaxvalue')
          echo get_post_meta( $cptid, 'offers_max_value', true );        
     if ( $colname == 'dateofend')
          echo date("j M y H:i:s", (get_post_meta( $cptid, '_sale_price_dates_to', true )+60*60) );
     if ( $colname == 'offerlefttime') {
          $atime = time();
          $d = (get_post_meta( $cptid, '_sale_price_dates_to', true ) - $atime)/(60*60*24);
          $h = ( get_post_meta( $cptid, '_sale_price_dates_to', true ) - $atime - ( (60*60*24) * explode(".", $d)[0] ) )/(60*60);
          $m = ( get_post_meta( $cptid, '_sale_price_dates_to', true ) - $atime - ( (60*60*24) * explode(".", $d)[0] ) - ( (60*60) * explode(".", $h)[0] ) )/(60);
          echo floor($d) . "d " . floor($h) . "h " . floor($m) . "m";
     }
}
add_action('manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'my_cpt_column', 10, 2);

// asl sortowanie
add_filter('manage_edit-product_sortable_columns', 'my_cpt_columns');
function my_sort_metabox( $vars ) {
      if( array_key_exists('orderby', $vars )) {
           if('OfferId' == $vars['orderby']) {
                $vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
                $vars['meta_key'] = 'offers_max_id';
           }
           if('Offers' == $vars['orderby']) {
                $vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
                $vars['meta_key'] = 'offers_count';
           }      
           if('Amount' == $vars['orderby']) {
                $vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
                $vars['meta_key'] = 'offers_max_value';
           }              
          if('EndTime' == $vars['orderby']) {
                $vars['order'] = 'ASC';
                $vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
                $vars['meta_key'] = '_sale_price_dates_to';
           }    
      }
      return $vars;
}
add_filter('request', 'my_sort_metabox');

// asl dodanie kolumny wynikowej z czasem do końca
function my_cpt_column_time( $columns ) {
    $columns["offerlefttime"] = "LeftTime";
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-product_columns', 'my_cpt_column_time');
```

And everything nice but one thing doesn't work. I want to have the products sort by column 'EndTime' ASC. 
Any suggestions?